# What is a good practice to using a DBHelper (SQLite) on Android Applications

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a DatabaseHelper class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper, what is a good practice to using the DBHelper to perform data extractions?

In my DatabaseHelper class, I have a method to help me retrieve the results of a query like, "Select * FROM .....". The results will be used by many other classes.

Example:

```
Cursor getAllWhitelist(){
     SQLite Database db=this.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("Select * from WhiteList");
     return cur;
}
```

Should I be returning a cursor at this stage? Is it recommended? Or should I be returning an ArrayList or things like that?

How are you guys doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i used is, stored the value in some object or in some arraylist of object and return that
Refer this [link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/0/page/1)

Thanks @Austyn Mahoney, as he told we can return cursor, if we use `startManagingCursor`.  This method allows the activity to take care of managing the given Cursor's lifecycle for you based on the activity's lifecycle.

Comment: Returning a cursor is just fine, you just need to make sure you add a `startManagingCursor(cursor)` call in your activity once the cursor is passed back to it.  You will need a cursor that isn't closed if you want to use it in a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks @Austyn Mahoney for that information. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to create a result list and close the cursor and the database in order to minimize the connection time. Otherwise, you can get your connection closed due to some constraints. This will be bad for your result list.

Comment: Would the exception to this be if you need the cursor for a ListView adapter? Google's example demonstrates using a cursor for this.

Comment: the thing is that cursor isn't necessary connected to database. Cursor is a general interface to fetch some data from any content provider.

Comment: @Thomas would you care the share a snippet of that example?

Comment: An example of this can be seen in one of Google's tutorials http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html See the fillData() function. They return a cursor of the items, manage it, and then feed it to a SimpleCursorAdaptor.

Comment: @Vladimir you are assuming that the result list is small, if this isn't the case, then you are going to waste resources reading the whole list into memory.